# How can I make my navigation ul li background fill the entire navbar?

Tags: css, navbar, padding, margin

I'm creating a simple website for my intro to web design class. I'm trying to make a centered navbar with six list items. As the user hovers over an item, the background changes from teal to white. My issue is that this white background doesn't extend all the way to the left.

I've tried experimenting with different paddings and margins, but each time the white overflows on the right but doesn't go to the left. Changing the display of the a to block doesn't help either.

```css
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  line-height: 2;
  font-family: Garamond, Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #023436;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a#navigation {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="media/header2.png" alt="Reading Record Header" id="headerlogo">
  <nav class="horizontal" id="navbar">
    <a href="#" id="navigation"><img src="media/naviconnobg.png"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="finalprojecthome.html" style="color:#ecb9a7;">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="finalprojectlog.html" style="color:#ecb9a7;">Log</a></li>
      <li><a href="finalprojectcontact.html" style="color:#ecb9a7;">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="finalprojectwriting.html" style="color:#ecb9a7;">Original Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="finalprojectreviews.html" style="color:#ecb9a7;">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="finalprojectphotoshoots.html" style="color:#ecb9a7;">Photoshoots</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Sorry if I did this wrong, it's my first time posting here. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I've edited your question in order to add a [stack snippet](//stackoverflow/help/reprex), from your posted code; please could you verify that demo to ensure it accurately reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use css reset in your project to reset the browser's default values.

in your code, ul has padding on the left side. using `padding-left:0;` Your problem will be solved.

In this situation, using the browser's inspect element (DevTools) can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm working on a computer that has devtools disabled, but I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: you're welcome. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:
`left:0;`
or:
`body{ margin:0; padding:0; }`
to your CSS file